# Splitting a string into an array then splitting the array again

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I have this string:

```
   fname lname, GTA V: 120 : 00000, Minecraft : 20 : 10, Assassin’s Creed IV : 90 : 800, Payday 2 : 190 : 2001 ,Wolfenstein TNO : 25 : 80, FarCry 4 : 55 : 862
```

I want to use a loop to split this string into an array at the comma [,] example:

```
[0]fname lname
[1]GTA V: 120 : 00000
[2]Minecraft : 20 : 10
[3]Assassin’s Creed IV : 90 : 800
[4]Payday 2 : 190 : 2001
[5]Wolfenstein TNO : 25 : 80
[6]FarCry 4 : 55 : 862
```

Then I want to use another loop to split this further at : into another array example

```
[0]fname lname
[1]GTA V
[2]120
[3]00000
[4]Minecraft
[5]20
[6]10
....
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

currently I have:

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
      lines.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

    //converts the list array to string array 

    String[] scanarray = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    //converts the string array into one large string

    String str_array = Arrays.toString(scanarray);

    String[] arraysplit;


    arraysplit = str_array.split("\\s*:\\s*");

    for (int i=0; i<arraysplit.length; i++)
    {
        arraysplit[i] = arraysplit[i].trim();
        //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ has values with spaces
        System.out.println(scanarray[i]);
    }
```

EDIT:

Currently my program creates 3 identical arrays, containing the example you can see in the second block of code above.

Comment: How do you define "better"? What is your goal?

Comment: Better in the sense that, I can just use one loop to do what is specified as appose to using two loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split method from String class with multiple delimiters

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myOriginalString = "   fname lname, GTA V: 120 : 00000, Minecraft : 20 : 10, Assassin’s Creed IV : 90 : 800, Payday 2 : 190 : 2001 ,Wolfenstein TNO : 25 : 80, FarCry 4 : 55 : 862";
    // | is the regex OR operator
    String[] splited = myOriginalString.split(",|:");
    for(String s : splited)
    System.out.println(s.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it what you are looking for with REGEX, just put what all thing you get separated with string **split** method.

I tried below code locally and it is pretty much same what you are looking for.

```
public class StackSol1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        String str = "fname lname, GTA V: 120 : 00000, Minecraft : 20 : 10, Assassin’s Creed IV : 90 : 800, Payday 2 : 190 : 2001 ,Wolfenstein TNO : 25 :80, FarCry 4 : 55 : 862";
        String delimiters = "\\s+|,\\s*|\\:\\s*";

        // analyzing the string
        String[] tokensVal = str.split(delimiters);

        // prints the number of tokens
        System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + tokensVal.length);

        String finalStr="";

        for (String token : tokensVal) {

            finalStr = finalStr+"\n"+token;
        }

        System.out.println(finalStr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using split with regex? e.g.

```
String aa = "fname lname, GTA V: 120 : 00000, Minecraft : 20 : 10, Assassin’s Creed IV : 90 : 800, Payday 2 : 190 : 2001 ,Wolfenstein TNO : 25 : 80, FarCry 4 : 55 : 862";
String [] a = aa.split("[,:]");
```